# How to inject property to interceptor in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I changed my spring mvc application configuration from xml to code.
since the change, all the injected properties in my interceptors are null (authenticationService).

the code looks like this:

```
public class WebAuthenticationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {


    @Resource(type=WebAuthenticationService.class)
    private IAuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {


        if(authenticationService.authenticate(request).authenticated == false)
        {
            if(isAjax(request))
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            else
                response.sendRedirect(String.format("%s/#/account/logout", request.getContextPath()));

            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

    public static boolean isAjax(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With"));
    }
}
```

and the interceptor config:

```
@Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        registry.addInterceptor(new WebAuthenticationInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/home/**");
        registry.addInterceptor(new MobileAuthenticationInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/api/**");
    }
```

Could you please state what am i doing wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: You are creating object using `new` keyword. Instead try defining `WebAuthenticationInterceptor` and `MobileAuthenticationInterceptor` as `@Bean` in your Spring config.

Comment: @dimchez Add that as an answer.

Comment: @TomG ok, posted my comment as an answer

Answer (score 4):

You are creating object using `new` keyword. Instead try defining `WebAuthenticationInterceptor` and `MobileAuthenticationInterceptor` as `@Bean` in your Spring config

Answer (score 0):

Injection is made by Spring annotation and since 3.x version it works also with java annotation (@Inject).

use

```
@Autowired
private IAuthenticationService authenticationService;
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. Consider reviewing your answer.

Comment: I ment to use @Autowired annotation to inject dependencies. Probably it's not the only problem in this case as I see right now after 3 years, but still using that annotation seems to be a correct way.