# Spring interceptor dependency injection

Tags: spring-mvc

I have springmvc and angularjs app up and running.
In Springmvc i have a bean named userSessionBean.
Now i am adding an interceptor to spring mvc and in its pre handel method i am trying to access userSessionBean.

My question is "Can i inject userSessionBean inside interceptor "

```
/**
* 
*/
package com.loginLite.remote.authentication.interceptors;

import java.util.Random;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;




import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.remote.authentication.model.UserSessionBean;

/**
 * @author jamju02
*
*/
public class AuthenticationInteceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
@Autowired
private UserSessionBean userSessionBean = null;

/**
 * @return the userSessionBean
 */
public UserSessionBean getUserSessionBean() {
    return userSessionBean;
}

/**
 * @param userSessionBean the userSessionBean to set
 */
public void setUserSessionBean(UserSessionBean userSessionBean) {
    userSessionBean = userSessionBean;
}

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Pre-handle");

    return true;
}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
        ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int tokenNumber = 100000 + rnd.nextInt(900000);
    userSessionBean.setAuthTokenNumber(String.valueOf(tokenNumber));
     response.addHeader("AUTH_TOKEN",userSessionBean.getAuthTokenNumber());
    System.out.println("Post-handle");
}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
        throws Exception {
    System.out.println("After completion handle");
}

}
```

My dispatcher servlet

```
<mvc:interceptors>
  <bean class="com.paychex.loginLite.remote.authentication.interceptors.AuthenticationInteceptor">
    <property name="userSessionBean" ref="userSessionBean"></property>
  </bean>
</mvc:interceptors> 


<bean id="userSessionBean"
    class="com.paychex.loginLite.remote.authentication.model.UserSessionBean"
    scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy />
</bean>
```

Comment: Yes i tried the above mentioned code, userSessionBean object is null,

Comment: What does your configuration look like?

Comment: That should work. You can remove the `@Autowired` and the `= null`.

Comment: removed but still same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inject property to interceptor in Spring MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211916/how-to-inject-property-to-interceptor-in-spring-mvc)

Answer (score -2):

I was finally able to solve the issue which i was troubling me.
The mistake was, i was implementing the interface "HandlerInterceptor" for my interceptor class, as soon as i removed the interface and extended class "HandlerInterceptorAdapter" dependency injection started working fine.